# Egrep - Search for multiple words and also restrict filetype

Tags: string, search, grep, file-type

I am trying to run a search across a network folder using egrep, but it is not working as I had hoped.

I am trying to search for text documents (files with extension txt only) that contain both string1 and string2 thus:

```
egrep -wir --include=\*.txt 'string1' * | egrep -wir --include=\*.txt 'string2' * > listofiles.txt
```

However, I am getting results from files that have other extensions (for example, .php files).

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

You're piping the output of the first egrep into the second egrep, which means you're grepping on the output of the first egrep, not the files it's returning. If all you want is files that contain both string1 and string2 a simple solution is running both egreps to the same file, then sort, uniq, and sort again:

```
egrep -wirl --include=\*.txt 'string1' * > listoffiles.txt
egrep -wirl --include=\*.txt 'string2' * >> listoffiles.txt
sort listoffiles.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort
```

Anything with a count of 2 is what you're looking for.

Note: egrep's -l flag suppresses normal output and only gives the file name

Note: uniq's -c flag gives you a count of how many occurences of the line were found

Comment: Hi Numeral - Not sure I understand.  The command in my OP successfully gives me all the files that contain both string1 and string2.  The issue is that I want to only check files with extension txt.  However, what you say does make me wonder, perhaps I should only restrict the filetype on the first egrep, but not the second?  I can't try that from here, so it will be tomorrow before I can test and post back.  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Hi - There is something more fundamentally wrong with what I am doing.  This command (not sure how to make it format correctly in these little responses that we are supposed to use so I'll 'wrap' it inside double Xs):XXegrep -wir --include=\*.txt 'string1' * > listoffiles.txtXX still gives me php files (as well as txt files), so my issue does not appear to be with the pipe?  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Hi - Please note that the forum removes the slash after the equals sign and I can't make it show up in the post - however it is there when I use the command.  Thanks, Alan.

Comment: Are you sure you're understanding how egrep works? egrep returns the name of the file and then the line that matched your query. By piping one egrep into the next egrep you're simply doing a grep on the matched lines, not the files themselves.

Comment: Hi Numeral - I wasn't, but I have a better understanding now thanks to you :-)  So, is there no way to achieve what I want to do with a 'single pass', rather than running the two separate egreps?  The reason I ask is that sometimes this search has to be run across a network drive with lots of files and directories, so it would seem to be ideal if I could do it once rather than twice if possible.  Thanks again, Alan.

Comment: Thought - Could I output the entire file from the first grep using something like this: grep -E "string1|$" *, and then grep that output for string2 perhaps?  Not at my PC right now, so I can't test it just yet.

Comment: Doing a logical and with regex isn't really ideal, better to just do it in multiple commands. What you can do is use xargs to to feed the output of one egrep to a second egrep so that the second egrep is only searching on files found in the first egrep.